# Zsh-Git-Prompt doesn't work on mac osx snow leopard

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I want to use the zsh-git-prompt, from this repo https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt, I've been using it on linux for a while and I haven't have any problems with it, now I'm trying to use it on Snow Leopard, but for some reason, the zsh functions are not called correctly, so it doesn't work and not throw any error messages.

I tried to executing the update_current_git_vars functions and it worked well, the problem is that functions aren't executed when change directory or things like that, but the reason of that I don't know.

My dotfiles are found here https://github.com/fespinoza/dotfiles/tree/mac

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try installing oh-my-zsh - https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

It works great on snow leopard and contains a number of theme files with customised prompts for zsh as well as plugins for autocompletion.

As for your prompt, should the $ be after the first quote mark? Or you could try leaving it out altogether?

Edit: And this is what i use as my path:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would **highly** recommend using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to manage your ZSH shell settings.

It provides capabilities to build a rich git-prompt; have a look at the provided themes for examples.

**Edit**:

A screenshot of my prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

zsh-git prompt works on my linux machine but if i ssh into that machine using putty it doesn't work. I am using monospaced font but it seems like i have to use correct encoding.